# type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean in lotto program

Tags: java

I am trying to make a lotto java program. I prompt the user to input their number and then generate a random number and if your number matches, you win but i'm getting the "type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean." Here's what I have so far. Thank you for the help! 
*Note i'm very new to java*

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class lottery
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your number");
    Random randomNumber=new Random();
    System.out.println(" my random number is "+65);
    System.out.println("lotto number is "+randomNumber.nextInt(10)+1);
    if(65)
      System.out.println("You win 20000");
    else 
      Sytem.out.println("No winner");
    if(56)
      System.out.println("You win 10000");
    else
      System.out.println("No winner");
    if(6||5)
      System.out.println("You win 5000");
    else
      System.out.println("No winner");

  }
}
```

Comment: What the heck does `if (65)` mean? That makes no sense. It's like asking "if green". Compare your **number variable** to 65 within the if statement. `if (randomNumber == 65)` -- now that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the random number in a variable and compare it in the if statements:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class lottery
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your number");
    Random randomNumber=new Random();
    int rand = randomNumber.nextInt(10) + 1
    System.out.println(" my random number is "+65);
    System.out.println("lotto number is "+ rand);
    if(rand == 65)
      System.out.println("You win 20000");
    else if(rand == 56)
      System.out.println("You win 10000");
    else if(rand == 6 || rand == 5)
      System.out.println("You win 5000");
    else
      System.out.println("No winner");
  }
}
```

Note: I fixed up your if statements a bit aswell. (You're still a winner if you get 56 right)